# many small inserts - better to batch them up or use prepared statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I'm running a software that generates on the order of a few million small data pieces and needs to put them into the DB as quickly as possible.

At this time I'm using prepared statements and optimized the DB (Postgres 9.6) for small inserts and got fairly good performance. But I'm wondering if it would speed up things even further if instead of prepared statements I would batch up the data so I don't insert every row individually.

I've done some research on the question but found no conclusive answer.

My data is reasonably small (5-10 values per row) and purely numerical (i.e. no strings, but a mix of integers, floats and booleans). My tables use serials as the primary key but no other indexes. I'm inserting into multiple tables that are linked by foreign keys. I have five prepared statements at this time, one for each table. Each statement inserts one row because I cannot tell in advance how many rows I will get.

My statements are trivial - no math, conditions or anything, basically they all look like this:

```
conn.prepare("INSERT INTO event 
(sc_id, r_id, th_id, tc, rs, is_te, is_le, total) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) 
RETURNING id")
```

---

I'm using Postgresql 9.6 on fast storage that I've already benchmarked and found to not be a bottleneck. My software is written in Rust and can generate data about two orders of magnitude faster than the DB can store it. I've already go a 4x increase in performance by optimising the Postgres configuration and I think that's most of what I'll get from that.

I am also running in parallel threads, each one inserting sets of data that are independent from each other.

The DB server is on the same physical machine as the data generator, and I'm connecting via socket, not TCP.

Answer (score 2):

You can gain something with multi-row inserts:

```
INSERT INTO xyz (col1, col2, ...) VALUES
   (...),
   (...),
   ...
```

The gain here is that you have fewer client-server round trips.

But the fastest would be to use the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html) statement. This way you can load data either from a file on the database machine or via the client connection.

If all that does not saturate your I/O subsystem, insert data in multiple database sessions in parallel.